# Scala - Handling UTF-8 BOM in String loaded from file

Tags: xml, scala, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Problem: Correctly handling UTF-8 BOM when loading a file into a Scala String. The String will be used as input into XML.

Note: The call scala.xml.XML.loadString() stack dumps if I do not remove the BOM from the String.

I am looking for advice on how to correctly load the file into a String. I am aware of scala.xml.XML.loadFile() which correctly loads a file with BOM into XML, but I need to do preprocessing of the String first.

Scala Version: 2.11.8

Code:

```
import scala.xml.XML
import scala.compat.Platform.EOL

object Test {
        val filename = "Tags_small.xml"         // BOM present
        // val filename = "Tags_test.xml"       // BOM removed

        def main(args: Array[String]) {
                // The Tags.xml has BOM at the start of the file
                // The replace() removes the UTF-8 BOM. 
                // FIX: Not elegant, but works for now

                val lines = readFile(filename)

                val xml = scala.xml.XML.loadString(
                            lines.replace("\u00EF\u00BB\u00BF", ""))

                println(xml + EOL)
        }

        def readFile(filename: String): String = {
                val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile(filename)
                val lines = bufferedSource.mkString
                bufferedSource.close
                return lines
        }
}
```

Hex display of input data (only three lines). Notice the first three bytes are UTF-8 BOM:

```
0000: EF BB BF 3C 3F 78 6D 6C - 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E   ...<?xml -  version
0010: 3D 22 31 2E 30 22 20 65 - 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D   ="1.0" e - ncoding=
0020: 22 75 74 66 2D 38 22 3F - 3E 0D 0A 3C 74 61 67 73   "utf-8"? - >..<tags
```

[EDIT 8/20/2018 with latest attempt]

I have modified readFile to use apache.commons BOMInputStream and this works. However, I have no experience with this library and its impact on my code (Apache Spark).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream

    def readFile(filename: String): String = {
            val inStream = new FileInputStream(filename)

            val content = io.Source.fromInputStream(
                            new BOMInputStream(inStream)).mkString

            inStream.close()

            content
    }
```

Comment: I would go with your usage of BOMInputStream, its designed for the use case you have - apache.commons.io is actually a dependency for spark-core as well as many other libraries - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/usages

Comment: Thank you. Now to add tests to verify the new code.

Comment: For those of you that are following this thread, over the next few days I am going to dig pretty deep into how Unicode and text files are loaded into memory as byte arrays and strings. I will post my results once I have completed this. I feel that bufferedSource.mkString should have handled this case. Now to find out what it does and does not support. The same for BOMInputStream. Maybe the issue lies with scala.xml.XML.loadString and its handling of Unicode.

Comment: The test files that I am using came from StackOverflow's data dumps. https://archive.org/download/stackexchange